# Python writes float to Postgresql but it is precision is lesser

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am writting such float value from Python `(6.481044303797468)` converted to string via StringIO `'6.481044303797468'` into Postgresql column of type `NUMERIC(13,8)`. I read it back into Python which is returned as `Decimal('6.48104430')`.

Why the precision is smaller?

Comment: `NUMERIC(13,8)` means the precision of 8.

Answer (score 2):

`NUMERIC(13,8)` means: 8 decimal digits. So you are getting exactly what you saved.

Answer (score 0):

You asekd to remember just 8 digits after decimal point in here
NUMERIC(13,8) change type for what your precision is desired